# How do you select all inputs inside a div with variables in its ID?

Tags: jquery

I want to target all input fields inside of this DIV. But I can't seem to target it correctly. I keep getting: **SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

```
var nameid= $.parseQuery(url_string).nameid;
var deleteuserid = $.parseQuery(url_string).deleteuserid;

$('#memberRow_' + nameid + '_' + deleteuserid).attr("disabled", true); //works
$('#memberRow_' + nameid + '_' + deleteuserid :input).attr("disabled", true); //doesn't work
```

The div ID I want to target basically looks like "#memberRow_33_32" or whatever the two variables end up being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some quotes to indicate the rest of the string here:

```
$('#memberRow_' + nameid + '_' + deleteuserid :input)
```

Should be:

```
$('#memberRow_' + nameid + '_' + deleteuserid + ' :input')
```

The `' :input'` part of the selector is a string, not a JavaScript operator.

Comment: the pseudo selector ":input" includes `radio`, `button` and `textarea` and therefore is not the same a `input`

Comment: @Josh: Ah, I didn't know that.  Corrected the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @David "The ' :input' part of the selector is a string, not a JavaScript operator." I didn't realize that! Now the whole thing makes sense! Thank you very much for the fast response!

Answer (score 2):

`$('#memberRow_' + nameid + '_' + deleteuserid + " :input").attr("disabled", true); //work`

Comment: For the record this works as well. Wrapping the :input in " instead of ' works.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$(function(){
 #(":input",$('#memberRow_' + nameid + '_' + deleteuserid)).attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```